# API For KMP or Boyer-Moore string pattern matching in C++ / STL?

Tags: c++, string, stl

Wondering, if I want to replace strstr with a better string matching algorithm, like KMP or Boyer Moore, is there one in C++ or do we have to write on our own?

Wondering, what is the practical string matching function that everyone uses other than strstr?

This is with respect to C++/STL under Unix/Linux platform.

Comment: That's actually a good question, I was wondering the same right now..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't seen many that use features specific to C++, but there are quite a few implementations of KMP and (especially) variants of Boyer-Moore (e.g., [Boyer-Moore-Horspool](https://github.com/vonj/snippets/blob/master/bmhsrch.c)) around that are easily usable from C++.

Comment: @mtk: I've fixed the link. Thanks.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Thanks